# Excel -- how to return certain values if cells in a column match multiple criteria

Tags: if-statement, excel-formula, countif, multiple-conditions

I want to search for certain values in a column and return specific words based on those values.

In the screenshot below, I'd like rows B-D to function as one. So only return "Pumpkin Pie", "Cookies", and "Rice". The rest will fall into "Other"

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

=IF(COUNTIF(A2,"*Pumpkin*")>0,"PumpkinPie",IF(COUNTIF(A2,"*Cookies*")>0,"Cookies",IF(COUNTIF(A2,"*Rice*")>0,"Rice","Other")))

Comment: @Sheena : The asterisk is not showing when I pasted my formula. Be sure of course, to include it within the search criteria for Countif  as you have in your example formula  immediately before and after  your search criteria text.